# Sphinx Python ImportError: cannot import name

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I am using [Sphinx](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/). When executing the command `make html`, my files that define an abstract class or are derived from an abstract class are getting an error.

### Error

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sphinx/ext/autodoc.py", line 529 
in import_object
    __import__(self.module)
File "/home/pi/.../abstractNode.py", line 6, in <module>
    from abc import ABC, abstractclassmethod
ImportError: cannot import name ABC
```

### Code referenced

Minimal example:

File: `abstractNode.py`

```
from abc import ABC, abstractclassmethod

class abstractNode(ABC):
    '''
    abstract parent
    '''
    @abstractmethod
    def moduleNode(self, parameter=[]):
        '''
        Implement Node Functionality here
        '''
        pass
```

File: `Node.py`

```
from foo.bar import abstractNode

class Node(abstractNode):
    '''
    implementation of abstract parent
    '''

    def moduleNode(self, parameter=[]):
        '''
        implementation written here
        '''
        pass
```

The result is that the documentation for those abstract class dependencies are nearly empty, whereas classes not using ABC are fine.

It doesn't have any problem importing any other package.

Comment: Where is the `abc` module relative to `foo.py`? Could it be a circular import? It's impossible to say without the source code of your package.

Comment: [abc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html) is a part of the python standard library, so it's at `/usr/lib/python[version]` with version being 2.7, 3.5 or any other python version installed, sitting right there with other modules like `os` or `pickle` that I'm also using.

That's why I didn't write it in the question and why I'm so puzzled

Comment: The class `ABC` in the module `abc` is newer than Python 2.7. It won't work with Python 2, only with Python 3.

Comment: Your code is for Python 3.4 or later (the ABC class was added in 3.4), but you run Sphinx with Python 2.7.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [pierre-de-buyl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3327666/pierre-de-buyl) and [mzjn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/407651/mzjn). You indeed identified the problem:

Although ABC and abstract classes are defined in [2.7 documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/abc.html), and are present in /usr/lib/python2.7, you must force sphinx to use python 3.x

Unfortunately I have not found an elegant method to do so, but my method descibed below solves the problem:

1. Uninstall sphinx
2. Install sphinx with python3:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install python3-sphinx
   ```

   or

   ```
   sudo pip3 install sphinx
   ```

   (in contrast to `python-sphinx` or `pip install`)
3. Create a sphinx documentation the way you are used to

(maybe someone has a better idea to force sphinx to use python 3.x?)